# How to increment the filename if file already exists in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have implemented Drag and Drop File Upload in my react project, so on every drag and drop of file into the drop zone , I'm taking the file and accessing it's name and it's data and converting the data to base64 using javscript's `FileReader()` and `readAsDataURL()` and updating the state, which I need to send it to bakend.

**How to append a number to filename if the file with same name already exist in the state ?**

eg: `file(1).csv`  or  `file 2.csv`

[image]

Main State

```
this.state : {
     Files:[],
}
```

Function that get's triggered every time for drag and drop of file

```
   FileHandling = (files) => {
    files.forEach((file) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = () => {

        const CompleteData= {
          fileData: reader.result,
          fileName: file.name,
        };
         this.setState({
             Files:[...this.state.Files, CompleteData]
            })
      };
    });
  };
```

Comment: Can't you do a check to see if the `Files` array already contain the filename? and modify the filename if so?

Comment: How to do that using javascript ?  I'm sending the object ```CompleteData``` to the array, and  Tried with ```includes()``` method, but it did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check `this.state.Files` before. A recursive function could be used here. Imagine you load a file named `export.csv`. The second one would `export.csv` transformed in `export_1.csv`. But on a third one named `export.csv`, the verification would be done on `export`, leading to `export_1` => Error !
The best is to do :

```
const checkNameOfTheFile = (newFileName) => {
    // Ex 'export.csv'
    const counter = this.state.Files.filter(f => f.fileName === newFileName).length;
    // If counter >= 2, an error has already been passed to the files because it means
    // 2 files have the same name
    if (counter >= 2) {
        throw 'Error duplicate name already present';
    }
    if (counter === 0) {
        return newFileName
    }
    if (counter === 1) {
        const newName = `${newFileName.split('.')[0]}_${counter}.${newFileName.split('.')[1]}`;
        // Return export_1.csv;
        return checkNameOfTheFile(newName);
        // We need to check if export_1.csv has not been already taken.
        // If so, the new name would be export_1_1.csv, not really pretty but it can be changed easily in this function
    }
};


const CompleteData= {
    fileData: reader.result,
    fileName: checkNameOfTheFile(file.name),
};
```

Comment: This works correctly :) , but the only problem here is every time counter will be counter = 0 . so whenever the duplicate file is added , filename will be ```Eg: file_1.csv , file_1.csv```

Comment: You are right, I wrote that too quickly. I propose a correction

Comment: I realize an example would lead to an error @jarivak, here is a new solution

Answer (score 4):

Make any pattern that you want on the line with a comment.

```js
 const getUniqueName = (fileName, index = 0) => {
   let checkName = fileName, ext = '';
   if(index){
     if(checkName.indexOf('.') > -1){
       let tokens = checkName.split('.'); ext = '.' + tokens.pop();
       checkName = tokens.join('.');
     }

     // make any pattern here
     checkName = `${checkName} (${index})${ext}`; 
   }
   
   const nameExists = this.state.Files.filter(f=>f.fileName === checkName).length > 0;
   return nameExists ? getUniqueName(fileName, index + 1) : checkName;
 }

 FileHandling = (files) => {
    files.forEach((file) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = () => {
        const CompleteData = {
          fileData: reader.result,
          fileName: getUniqueName(file.name),
        };
         this.setState({
             Files:[...this.state.Files, CompleteData]
            })
      };
    });
  };
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is giving me an Error , ```RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded```

Comment: If you can share the current state.Files and file.name — I can debug the solution. It has a recursion approach and I understand how it can fail on 10000 files with the same names, but I do not think that it is your case.
Also send me the template if you modified it.

Answer (score 2):

Determine if there is a matching file, if so determine if it is already a duplicate (has a number at the end already). If so find its number and increment it. Otherwise just append a '1'. If there are no matching files, don't do anything.

```
FileHandling = (files) => {
files.forEach((file) => {
  const reader = new FileReader();

  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  reader.onload = () => {
    let existingFiles = this.state.Files.filter(x=>x.fileName==file.Name);
    let fileName = file.Name;
    if(existingFiles.length > 0) {
      let oldFileName = existingFiles[0].split('.')[0];
      let oldFileMatchNumberMatch = oldFileName.match(/\d+$/);
      let fileNumber = (oldFileMatchNumberMatch) parseInt(oldFileMatchNumberMatch[0], 10) : 1;
      fileName = file.Name + fileNumber; //if file.Name has an extension, you'll need to split, add the number to the end of the 0'th element, and rejoin it
    }

    const CompleteData= {
      fileData: reader.result,
      fileName: file.name,
    };
     this.setState({
         Files:[...this.state.Files, CompleteData]
        })
  };
});
```

Comment: I guess there is a syntax error @ ```let fileNumber = (oldFileMatchNumberMatch) parseInt(oldFileMatchNumberMatch[0], 10) : 1;```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, It's not exactly in the format of the question, but it seems to me that it can help.
Below is a simple js code, which goes through a list of strings representing file names, and computes the next name.
If the file 'file.png' exists once - it will be returned 'file(1).png'.
If the file 'file(1).png' also exists- it will be returned 'file(2).png', and etc.

```
let fileList=['fa.png','fb.mp4','fc.jpeg','fa(1).png'];

const getName=(fileName)=>{
  let [name,end]=fileName.split('.');
 let num = 0;
let curName = `${name}.${end}`;
let exists=fileList.filter(f => f === curName).length;
while(exists) {
  console.log('curName:',curName,'exists:',exists,'num:',num);
    curName = `${name}(${++num}).${end}`;
     exists=fileList.filter(f => f === curName).length;
  } 
  return curName;
}

console.log(getName('fa.png'));
```

[see in codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/getfilename-duplication-ukvrk?file=/src/App.js:24-482/)